# How to write a wrapper around bind_params?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'd like to write a wrapper function around mysqli's `bind_param`. In the [documentation](http://jp.php.net//manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) (OO style) the function signature is `bool mysqli_stmt::bind_param ( string $types , mixed &$var1 [, mixed &$... ] )`, so I wonder what my function's signature should be and how would I pass the parameters to `bind_param`.

I know about the `func_get_args` function but this would turn the parameters into an array and I have no idea what would happen to the by reference values. Is this even possible?

Comment: No, it's not possible that way for the reason you stated: the references are lost. It perhaps works with 5.6's variadic parameters, but I don't know specifically. - Also I suggest to search a little, I'm pretty sure you're not the first one with the idea, maybe others had some ideas how to work around or do alternatively :) - See [answer to *"PHP mysqli wrapper: passing by reference with __call() and call_user_func_array()"*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2567938/367456).

Comment: I think that'll just prevent me from having to write a wrapper around `bind_param` but writing this wrapper is exactly what I'm trying to do. I really just want to `die` whenever `bind_param` fails. How do php programmers usually handle this? Just run an error check every single time `bind_param` is called?

Comment: See my answer below, it's possible now since 5.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, as I first commented, you summarise the situation quite well and you lay the finger into the wound where this gets stuck:

- Passing by reference a variable number of parameters.

This is also the state of art in the [answer to *"PHP mysqli wrapper: passing by reference with __call() and call_user_func_array()"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2567938/367456) from April 2010 about the same topic.

So what is new this year is that with variadic functions which are new with PHP 5.6 ([RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/variadics)) *by-reference capture* is now possible. And the example in that [section](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/variadics#by-reference_capture) actually has the code you're most likely looking for:

> ```
> class MySQL implements DB {
>     public function prepare($query, &...$params) {
>         $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
>         foreach ($params as $i => &$param) {
>             $stmt->bindParam($i + 1, $param);
>         }
>         return $stmt;
>     }
>     // ...
> }
> ```

Find out more about that feature in the PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

Comment: Too bad my server is 5.3. I'll just write a wrapper around `die` LOL.

Comment: Okay, well, for 5.3 I think the idea is to extend from `Mysqli` and leave that method untouched.